# Receive SMS Sender and perform action without SMS Permissions

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I've created an app that allows for custom alerts such as ringtones etc based on the sender of a text message that is received for use by on-call emergency staff that may need to wake up at any hour of the day or night. I do this by processing the incoming SMS via a broadcast receiver using the **RECEIVE_SMS** permissions in order to get only the sender of the SMS.

Due to Google Play's decision to limit usage of these 'high risk' permissions

> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303,

I may be forced to remove my app. Is there another way I can receive the sender of an SMS so I can perform actions based on it or an alternative approach I could use?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to intercept them with a Notification Listener Service but in a lot of cases you won't get the information you need.

Its not possible to receive SMS data unless you get this permission. You can send an email requesting permission from Google for an exception for your app. They will allow it if you have a legitimate reason to do this. If you look at the link you posted it says under the Exceptions section one of them is

```
Caller ID, spam detection, and spam blocking
```

I would say your custom ringtones are a form of caller ID so you should state your case to google play and they should allow it.

Comment: Thank you, I had attempted to get an exception but I didn't make the argument that it was a form of Caller ID. The apps primary purpose is to ensure that on-call staff wake up during emergencies (Ie a text is received). Unfortunately it's not useful unless it can filter numbers.